# Close a FD (file descriptor) that was opened with shm_open() , without using close()?

Tags: c, file-descriptor

I want to close a FD that was opened with `shm_open` .

Here's the code :

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>             
 #include <sys/file.h>           
 #include <sys/mman.h>          
 #include <sys/wait.h>

 void errorAndExit(const char *msg)
 {
     perror(msg);
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
      /* shm_open recommends using a leading '/' in
      the region name for portability, but Linux
      doesn't require it. */

      const char *memname = "/myMkfifo.txt";

      // Use one page for this example

      const size_t region_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);

     /* Create the shared memory region.
      Notice the args are identical to open(2).*/

     int fd = shm_open(memname, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR, 0666);
     if (fd == -1)
         errorAndExit("shm_open");

    /* Allocate some memory in the region. We use ftruncate, but
     write(2) would work just as well. */

     int r = ftruncate(fd, region_size);
     if (r != 0)
         errorAndExit("ftruncate");

    // Map the region into memory.

     void *ptr =
         mmap(0, region_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd,
              0);
     if (ptr == MAP_FAILED)
         errorAndExit("mmap");

     // Don't need the fd after the mmmap call.

     close(fd);
     pid_t pid = fork();

     if (pid == 0)   // son
     {
         // Child process inherits the shared memory mapping.

         u_long *d = (u_long *) ptr;
         *d = 200;
         printf("I'm the child process and I wrote: %#lx\n", *(u_long *) d);
         exit(0);
     }


     else    
     {   /* child
          Synchronize with the child process. */

         int status;
         waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

         // Parent process sees the same memory.

         printf("I'm the father process , and my child wrote: %#lx\n", *(u_long *) ptr);

     }

     // errorAndExit with the memory, umap it.

     r = munmap(ptr, region_size);
     if (r != 0)
         errorAndExit("munmap");

     // Remove the shared memory region.

     r = shm_unlink(memname);
     if (r != 0)
         errorAndExit("shm_unlink");

    return 0;
}
```

How can I close the `fd` without `close()` ?

Thanks

Comment: According to http://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_open you use `shm_unlink()` to release a file descriptor obtained from `shm_open()`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @MatthewD: I'm already using that later in the code (meaning I'm using `shm_unlink()` , please see edited code) . I'm looking for some other way to close the `fd` in the line `close(fd)`.

Comment: Usually when you find you want to do "X without using Y", it's good form to explain *why*, since it can be quite frustrating with these seemingly random restrictions.

Comment: @unwind: I'm writing a program that is shared memory based ,without any `read` , `write` , `close` , `open` , or any other library calls using these system calls.

Comment: @ron: what's the point of not using `close`? What do you gain by not using it (assuming there was another syscall that worked in this case)?

Comment: just do `exit(0)` that closes all file descriptors

Comment: @JensGustedt : You mean `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);` ?

Comment: @Mat: That's what I'm trying to find out . The minute I would - I'll notify you .

Comment: @ron: what do you hope to gain? Why do you think `close` is a problem? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: I think you are trying to write smthng to area in child, then read those piece in father. In my opinion, There is no need to close or doing smthng else. After program terminates, it will gone.Am I wrong ?

Comment: @user315052: A lovely answer , why shouldn't I :) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like a puzzle to me: How do you close a file descriptor without calling close on the fd?  Here's one way:

```
int close_without_close (int fd) {
    if (dup2(!fd, fd) < 0) return -1; // assumes 0 and 1 are open
    return close(!fd);
}
```

Here's another:

```
int close_without_close2 (int fd) {
    if (fcntl(fd, fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) < 0) return -1;
    switch (fork()) {
    case -1: return -1;
    case 0:  break;
    default: exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Okay, the second doesn't work until after you `exec`. Oh well...

One more:

```
int close_without_close3 (int fd) {
    return syscall(SYS_close, fd);
}
```

Comment: @TomTanner: But ! on the `fd`.

Comment: @jxh: And it closes the wrong fd. All of the solutions in this answer are wrong, so I don't see why it's the accepted answer...

Comment: @R..: `dup2()` will close `fd` before duplicating `!fd` (most of the time `0`) onto it.

Comment: `dup2` does release the reference on the open file to which `fd` refers, but the file descriptor slot is then occupied by a reference to the open file serving as stdin or stdout. Moreover, you subsequently call close (which the question forbid) on stdin or stdout, which is generally a dangerous and incorrect thing to do.

Comment: @R..: So with `dup2()` I don't close the wrong `fd`. Closing descriptor `0` or `1` is sketchy, to be sure, but it's not like it doesn't have precedent.

Comment: Closing 0 or 1 is usually a serious bug that can lead to security compromise, data corruption, etc. The next file opened will get fd 0 or 1, and then code accessing stdin or stdout will steal input or write and clobber output on this unrelated file. Anyway I really fail to see why you included the `close` call at all since OP's problem was to avoid using `close`...

Comment: @R..: It was a joke. Assume the negation operator and the `close()` function call are commutative.

Answer (score 2):

This is a (costly...) way to get around close() ...

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
int val;
int fd = -1;

val = fcntl(fd, F_GETFD, 0);
val |= FD_CLOEXEC;
fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, val);

execve(argv[0], argv, NULL);
return 0; /* not reached */
}
```

Comment: It's also not correct. `argv[0]` need not be a valid pathname to your executable; it's an arbitrary string provided by the program that invoked your program.

Comment: The invocation of main can be controlled by the calling process (it could for instance set `argv[0] = "/bin/tine";`, but reading the question I conclude that the OP knows this stuff. It is also wrong in the sense that execXXX() unmaps all memory mappings. But genarally, I think that for a nonsensical question a nonsensical anwer is appropiate. And the idea (using close on exec) is not that bad.